# Crawl Space Wet Spot

Tags: crawlspace

My house is 65 yrs. old.  It has a 4' high crawl space with a gravel floor.  There is sheathing on the walls.  Plastic sheeting was placed on the floor when we bought it 37 years ago and we have had no problems.

Several years ago, I noticed a damp corner on the floor where it looks like sand has risen to the top of the gravel and there are white marks on the sheathing which came off easily with a scrub brush.

There was a dehumidifier in place (*with a bucket collector*) which failed but we have not replaced yet but will do so once the problem is solved.

How can we tell where the water is coming from and what should we do to correct it?

Comment: Water runs downhill. Look for backslope against the foundation, missing or clogged rain gutters, leaky pipes....

Comment: Pictures are always helpful. When you say floor, I'm guessing you mean the ground that's covered with the plastic, opposed to a finished interior floor? Your house is probably too old for foundation drains, but if you have one, it can also be clogged.

Comment: @Isherwood put that one in the answer box. Failing French drains could also be an issue but with 4’ crawl space I would not worry about 6” of water as long as my footings and pier blocks are above water.

Comment: @EdBeal Wow, I’ve never heard of anyone not caring about 6” of standing water under their house in a crawl space.

Comment: Well you must not live in an area like Oregon winters it is normal in many parts of the states to have standing water as long as your footings and foundations are well above the water. when it drys out so will the crawl space.

Answer (score 1):

Standing Water in a crawl space is never desirable. It causes so many problems:

1. Water attracts pests
2. Mold and fungus can grow fast.
3. Mold produces allergens and affect your respiratory system.
4. Hantavirus from pests. (HCF)
5. Microbial growth. This can lead to headaches, etc.

Actually I’ve done a few dozen projects on the Oregon coast and everything just doesn’t dry out and go away...even on the mid-coast area where it blows hard all the time. We’ll spend what it takes to get rid of standing water...drain it, pump it, do what you have to but don’t let it stand or you’ll have severe problems.

Here’s an article that helps explain:

https://www.nachi.org/crawlspace-hazards-inspection.htm

Google crawl space moisture and you’ll find many more articles too.

Note: These are just the health risks...not to mention construction problems.

To locate the problem, call an inspector. Water can be from a rising water table (seasonal) or from a roof drain directed towards the house.